# One column or two column?

Tags: mysql

A column contains a string.
In most cases it a small string (less than 50 characters).
But sometimes it can contains a big string (kilobytes).

What is more effective?

1. `field VARCHAR(65535) NOT NULL`
2. `field VARCHAR(255) NULL, field_big TEXT NULL`.
   If the value longer than 255 - write to `field_bid`, else - to `field`.

When read look at where not NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Unless when the string is larger then 50 characters you deal with it differently, you should store them as 1 column.

Splitting them into two columns will only complicate queries, you'll have to use `CASE EXPRESSION/IF` each time you want to deal with this column which will only result in unreadable queries!